# Cannot find the "theme" option in Prestashop

Tags: themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I cannot find the theme option in the preference menu bar (see the picture). PrestaShop version - 1.6.0.5

I installed a new theme but now I want to switch back to my default but I couldn't find any way to do it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eho6yz5e8ynz5c3/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-05%20at%202.35.44%20pm.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not logged in as super admin and you don't have permission to view themes with your current profile. You can check your profile in **Administration->Employees**. And you can check your permission in "**Administration->Permission**".

If you do not have permission then contact your super admin and ask to give you permission to make changes theme section.

If you are already a super admin. And still you don't see it,Then try following things.

**1)** Then try renaming the new theme from themes folder directory.

**2)** If you have access to database goto ps_shop table and change 'id_theme' to 1.